# Oracle iterate over text and find out which word matches several regular expressions

Tags: regex, oracle

I am facing  the following issue.
Need to split my regular expression into parts due to the lack of lookaround.
SO I want to match and word that is at least 7 chars long, consisting of capitals, _ and digits.

```
declare
pat1 constant varchar2(10) := '[A-Z]';
pat2 constant varchar2(10) := '[_]';
pat3 constant varchar2(10) := '[A-Z0-9_]{7,}';
begin
 IF regexp_like(myvar,pat1) AND regexp_like(myvar,pat2) AND regexp_like(myvar,pat3) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MATCH'||myvar);
 END IF;
END;
```

This will match both 
    myvar:='`A _ AAAABBC`' and myvar:='`AAAA_BB8`'. I want it to match only the second (has all 3 conditions), as the first one matches against 3 different strings: `A` `_` and `AAAABBC`. In addition, I need the precise word that matches.

Comment: Create a collection of varchar2 that store the patterns instead of individual variables. Then  loop through the collection. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html

Comment: Please describe the full requirement in plain English (no code). Perhaps it can be guessed from your code, but why ask us to do that - you should post the requirement and not expect us to guess.

Comment: why should it match only 2nd one not first one?

Comment: @GurV  I want it to match only the second (has all 3 conditions), as the first one matches against 3 different strings: A _ and AAAABBC.

Comment: OK, this is clearer. You want the words to have length at least 7, to include only uppercase letters, digits and underscore, and to include at least one underscore. Are there additional requirements (for example, there must be at least one letter, there must be EXACTLY one underscore, no more, etc.)? Actually, the first condition means you must have at least one letter. Any others? Also, is speed (performance) important? Standard (non-regexp) solutions may be much faster, but they may look more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the third pattern exactly. so you want to use `^[A-Z0-9_]{7,}$` instead

```
set serveroutput on
declare
pat1 constant varchar2(20) := '[A-Z]';
pat2 constant varchar2(20) := '[_]';
pat3 constant varchar2(20) := '^[A-Z0-9_]{7,}$';
myvar varchar2(1000);
begin
 myvar := 'A _ AAAABBC';
 IF regexp_like(myvar,pat1)
  AND regexp_like(myvar,pat2)
  AND regexp_like(myvar,pat3) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myvar);  -- Doesn't match
 END IF;

 myvar := 'AAAA_BB8';
 IF regexp_like(myvar,pat1)
  AND regexp_like(myvar,pat2)
  AND regexp_like(myvar,pat3) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myvar);  -- Matches
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is a solution for the concrete problem, which means I failed to describe precisely what I would like to do. In reality, my regex is more complex (a few more similar ones) and myvar gets its value from a clob (it is a file). I would like it to work only if there is a particular word that matches all regexes and currently it works in more cases: e.g. if there one word per regex in the clob (text file).

Comment: And eventually I would like to be able to return that word. Is there something more efficient than checking each word in the clob separately?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
declare
myvar varchar2(100) :='AAAA_A8';
begin
if regexp_like(myvar,'[A-Z]_[A-Z][0-9]') 
then
    dbms_output.put_line('MATCH'||myvar); end if;
END;
```

The code helps to identify pattern like Alphabets followed by _ and then alphabets followed by number. Hope it meets your requirement. The code matches for AAAA_A8 and AAAA_8.